# K&R binary search code

Tags: c, binary-search

I am studying K&R. He gives code for a particular function (binary search) but not a full program. What else besides main() do I need to get this running?

```
// binsearch: find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1]

#include <stdio.h>

int binsearch( int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (x < v[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (x > v[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else //found match
            return mid;
    }
    return -1; //no match
}
```

Comment: Technically, nothing else. Now what have you tried to put in your `main()` ?

Comment: Nothing. It's a complete function.

Comment: My main is 

int main()
{
 binsearch(91, v[100], 100);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Per its description, a binary search searches a value in a sorted array. Your `main` may or may not fit that, because the values in `v` seem not initialized.

Answer (score 4):

You don't show the declaration or initialization of the array `v` when you write:

> My main is `int main() { binsearch(91, v[100], 100); return 0; }`

If `v` is a global variable, it will be initialized with all zeros.  The notation `v[100]` would require `v` to be an array of at least 101 `int *`, and the element `v[100]` would need to point to an array of at least 100 `int` which are in sorted order.  More likely, what you meant and needed is something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int v[] =
    {
        -98, -96, -94, -93, -90, -89, -86, -86, -85, -83,
        -81, -75, -73, -73, -71, -69, -64, -63, -62, -62,
        -61, -61, -56, -54, -53, -50, -49, -47, -46, -43,
        -43, -43, -39, -38, -37, -34, -33, -32, -25, -25,
        -24, -21, -20, -16, -15, -14, -11, -10,  -9,  -5,
         -5,  -1,  +1,  +1,  +2,  +3,  +4, +16, +16, +18,
        +19, +19, +21, +21, +22, +23, +23, +24, +25, +25,
        +29, +30, +32, +33, +34, +35, +36, +37, +41, +52,
        +55, +57, +57, +57, +58, +59, +60, +61, +68, +68,
        +69, +70, +70, +75, +83, +83, +83, +91, +96, +97,
    };
    int x = binsearch(91, v, 100);

    if (x < 0)
        printf("Element 91 not found in array\n");
    else
        printf("Found 91 at entry %d (%d)\n", x, v[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

As an extension exercise, consider taking the value to look for from the arguments to the program instead of hardwiring 91 as the value.